# Input Text Box keeps getting erased, along with input effects

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, text

I'm trying to create a simple text input box. When the submit button is pressed, the input in the text box is sent to a search script that compares the input to an array of possible values.

However, once I press the submit button, the correct result of the function flashes quickly on the screen, after which the default value of the text box returns, and the function result disappears quickly again. This all happens in a matter of like 100 ms.

Could anyone explain how I can prevent this reset from happening? I've been looking online everywhere, and can only find people who are asking how to reset it, so I'm a bit confused as to what I'm doing wrong.

[Result after pressing submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58T1h.png)
[Result right after displaying the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHvKT.png)
Body:

```
<body>
<div id="blogmenu"></div>

<div ID="RECEPT">
<h1>Search Bar</h1>
<br>

<h2> Time for Searchin' </h2>

<form name="inputForm">                                                                                                                                                                                
    <div><input type="text" min="1" max="50" value="" class="slider" id="a" name="a"></div>
    <div><input type="submit" onclick="SearchItem(document.getElementById('a').value);"></div>
</form>

<div ID="ijsjes" style="display:none"> IJsjes </div>

<div ID="spaghetti" style="display:none"> Spaghetti </div>

<div ID="gniocchi" style="display:none"> Gniocchi </div>

<div ID="bananen" style="display:none"> Bananen </div>



</div>

</body>
```

Function:

```
<script>

function SearchItem(Term) {

    console.log('I did get here');
    document.getElementById('a').value = Term;

    var ijsjes = {
        kleur : "wit",
        smaak : "zoet",
        type : "dessert"
    };
    var spaghetti = {
        kleur : "geel",
        smaak : "hartig",
        type : "pasta"
    };
    var gniocchi = {
        kleur : "geel",
        smaak : "hartig",
        type : "pasta"
    };
    var bananen = {
        kleur : "geel",
        smaak : "zoet",
        type : "fruit"
    };

    console.log(spaghetti.kleur + " also " + (spaghetti.kleur == Term));

    if (ijsjes.kleur == Term) {
        document.getElementById('ijsjes').style.display = 'block';
        console.log('ijsjes matched');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('ijsjes').style.display = 'none';
        console.log('ijsjes not matched');
    }

    if (spaghetti.kleur == Term) {
        document.getElementById('spaghetti').style.display = 'block';
        console.log('spaghetti matched');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('spaghetti').style.display = 'none';
        console.log('spaghetti not matched');
    }

    if (gniocchi.kleur = Term) {
        document.getElementById('gniocchi').style.display = 'block';
        console.log('gniocchi matched');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('gniocchi').style.display = 'none';
        console.log('gniocchi not matched');
    }

    if (bananen.kleur = Term) {
        document.getElementById('bananen').style.display = 'block';
        console.log('bananen matched');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('bananen').style.display = 'none';
        console.log('bananen not matched');
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Your last 2 conditions (last 2 if-else block) are assigning value rather than comparing.

Comment: I noticed, that was not the problem though, it simply meant those values will always show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is of type `submit` which by default will result in the `onsubmit` function of your `form` being fired, which by default does a postback on your page

you can either drop the form and change your button to `type="button"` or move the function to the `onsubmit` property of the form (as in my snippet) and use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the post back

```js
function SearchItem(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var Term = document.getElementById('a').value;

  console.log('I did get here');
  document.getElementById('a').value = Term;

  var ijsjes = {
    kleur: "wit",
    smaak: "zoet",
    type: "dessert"
  };
  var spaghetti = {
    kleur: "geel",
    smaak: "hartig",
    type: "pasta"
  };
  var gniocchi = {
    kleur: "geel",
    smaak: "hartig",
    type: "pasta"
  };
  var bananen = {
    kleur: "geel",
    smaak: "zoet",
    type: "fruit"
  };

  console.log(spaghetti.kleur + " also " + (spaghetti.kleur == Term));

  if (ijsjes.kleur == Term) {
    document.getElementById('ijsjes').style.display = 'block';
    console.log('ijsjes matched');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('ijsjes').style.display = 'none';
    console.log('ijsjes not matched');
  }

  if (spaghetti.kleur == Term) {
    document.getElementById('spaghetti').style.display = 'block';
    console.log('spaghetti matched');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('spaghetti').style.display = 'none';
    console.log('spaghetti not matched');
  }

  if (gniocchi.kleur = Term) {
    document.getElementById('gniocchi').style.display = 'block';
    console.log('gniocchi matched');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('gniocchi').style.display = 'none';
    console.log('gniocchi not matched');
  }

  if (bananen.kleur = Term) {
    document.getElementById('bananen').style.display = 'block';
    console.log('bananen matched');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('bananen').style.display = 'none';
    console.log('bananen not matched');
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="blogmenu"></div>

  <div ID="RECEPT">
    <h1>Search Bar</h1>
    <br>

    <h2> Time for Searchin' </h2>

    <form name="inputForm"  onsubmit="SearchItem(event)">
      <div><input type="text" min="1" max="50" value="" class="slider" id="a" name="a"></div>
      <div><input type="submit"></div>
    </form>

    <div ID="ijsjes" style="display:none"> IJsjes </div>

    <div ID="spaghetti" style="display:none"> Spaghetti </div>

    <div ID="gniocchi" style="display:none"> Gniocchi </div>

    <div ID="bananen" style="display:none"> Bananen </div>



  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Your last 2 conditions (last 2 if-else block) are assigning value rather than comparing**.Because of this your value is printed for a while before getting over-ridden.
2. Also, **as soon as you find the element/search value, you should break/stop because other if/else statements would then overwrite previous results**.One way to achieve this would be to have nested if-else, so that the code execution continues only when the conditions/values are not being met.
3. The input type="button" **does a postback**, so you are using onclick function to call javascript so you do not need to submit the data anywhere. Just make input type="button" instead of "submit"